# Add row only once when found with multiple duplicate values javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to add row only once when found with multiple duplicate values.Here it adds rows according
to the number of **accountNumber == accountNumberInTable** found.I add a new record with say 
NS-01 and when i add another entry with the same record NS-01 it asks for one confirmation.
Again if i add the record with the same value of NS-01, it asks the confirmation twice since
there are two rows with the same record.

```js
$('#AddNewRowButton').click(function () {
    debugger;
    var index = $('#CollectionTable tbody tr').length;
    var imageButton = "<button type='button' style='background-color:transparent; margin-top:-4px;' class='btn btn-flat' id='DeleteImageButton' onmouseover=this.style.cursor='pointer'><i style='font-size:11px;' class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></i></button>";
    var statementReference = $('#StatementReferenceTextBox').val();
    var accountNumberId = $("#AccountNumberIdHiddenField").val();
    var accountNumber = $('#AccountNumberTextBox').val();
    var customerId = $('#CustomerIdTextBox').val();
    var name = $('#CustomerNameTextBox').val();
    var unit = $('#UnitTextBox').val();
    var collectorName = $('#CollectorsSelect :selected').text();;
    var productName = $('#ProductTextBox').val();
    var amount = parseFloat($('#AmountTextBox').val());
    if (isNaN(amount)) {
        amount = 0;
    }

    var amountTextBox = "<input type='text' id='TableAmountTextBox'" + "value=" + amount + " style='text-align:right;' />";

    if (amount == '' || accountNumber == '' || customerId == '') {
        $('#DialogDiv').empty();
        $('#DialogDiv').append('Cannot add empty values');
        $('#DialogDiv').slideDown(200);
        return;

    }

   
    var newRow = "<tr><td>" + imageButton + "</td><td>" + (index + 1) + "</td><td>" + statementReference +
        "</td><td style='display:none;'>" + accountNumberId + "</td><td>" + accountNumber + "</td><td>" + customerId + "</td><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + unit + "</td><td>" + collectorName + "</td><td>" + productName + "</td><td>" + amountTextBox + "</td></tr>";
    var alreadyExists = false;
    var i = collectionSheetDetails.length;
    $('#CollectionTable > tbody > tr').each(function () {      
            var accountNumberInTable = $(this).find('td:eq(4)').text();
            if (accountNumber == accountNumberInTable) {
                var r = confirm('There is already an entry with the same account number. Proceed anyway?');
                if (r == true) {
                    alreadyExists = true;
                    addNewRow(newRow);
                    calculateTotal();
                    clearReadOnlyFields();
                    if ($('#AccountNumberTextBox').prop('disabled') == false) {
                        $('#AccountNumberTextBox').focus();
                    }
                    enableDisableCollector();

                } else {
                    alreadyExists = true;
                    if ($('#AccountNumberTextBox').prop('disabled') == false) {
                        $('#AccountNumberTextBox').focus();
                        clearReadOnlyFields();
                        $('#AccountNumberTextBox').val('');

                    };
                }
            }
        

    });
    if (!alreadyExists) {
        addNewRow(newRow);
        calculateTotal();
        clearReadOnlyFields();
        if ($('#AccountNumberTextBox').prop('disabled') == false) {
            $('#AccountNumberTextBox').focus();
        }
        enableDisableCollector();
    }

    if ($('#NumberTextBox').prop('disabled') == false) {
        $('#NumberTextBox').focus();
    }
    if ($('#AccountNumberTextBox').prop('disabled') != true) {
        $('#AccountNumberTextBox').focus();
    }
    var colDiv = document.getElementById("CollectionSheetTable");
    console.log(colDiv);
    colDiv.scrollTop = colDiv.scrollHeight;

    //$("#CollectionTable").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "slow");
    return false;
});
```

How do i make it ask for confirmation only once
irrespective of the number of duplicate records.Help please.

Comment: your snippet shows an error, check for closing curly brackets and parenthesis of your `each` loop. Also, no need for this `if ($('#CollectionTable > tbody > tr').length > 0) ` inside your loop, if that condition is not true, it won't even go into the loop

Comment: i have added the whole addbutton code snippet sir

Comment: still shows me an error, check it out and see if you can do something about it: `{
  "message": "ReferenceError: $ is not defined",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 13,
  "colno": 9
}`. Well I think it's the fact that you have not included your jQuery file in the snippet, hence `"ReferenceError: $ is not defined"`, check that out

Comment: I have juery included sir..i have updated the snippet with if Check Removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, this is a useless check:

```
if ($('#CollectionTable > tbody > tr').length > 0)
```

You do this inside `$.each` loop for the same selector, so if the loop is running, you already know, it exists. Also, this will always give you length of the first found `<tr>`.

Answering your question: you need just to finish the loop after first duplicate confirmation. Use `return false;` for this purpose. It's equivalent to `break` in for-loop.

**Edit:** try to modify your `each` like this:

```
$('#CollectionTable > tbody > tr').each(function () {      
  var accountNumberInTable = $(this).find('td:eq(4)').text();
  if (accountNumber == accountNumberInTable) {
      var r = confirm('There is already an entry with the same account number. Proceed anyway?');
        if (r == true) {
          alreadyExists = true;
          addNewRow(newRow);
          calculateTotal();
          clearReadOnlyFields();
          if ($('#AccountNumberTextBox').prop('disabled') == false) {
            $('#AccountNumberTextBox').focus();
          }
          enableDisableCollector();
        } else {
          alreadyExists = true;
          if ($('#AccountNumberTextBox').prop('disabled') == false) {
            $('#AccountNumberTextBox').focus();
            clearReadOnlyFields();
            $('#AccountNumberTextBox').val('');
        };
      }
      return false;
    }
  });
```

Comment: @OLDMONK; maybe `return false;` is actually what is necessary here. `return true;` will cancel any further code execution within THE CURRENT ITERATION, and will go up and continue with the next iteration and on and on. On the other hand `return false;` will effectively cancel ALL FURTHER ITERATIONS and leave the loop. try this, good luck

Comment: @J.M.Echevarría, my bad, mixed them up

Comment: @OLDMONK; didn't work as in, it is still confirming more than once? Look, insert `console.log(accountNumber);` right after `if (accountNumber == accountNumberInTable) {`. check the console output

Comment: @J.M.Echevarría It is still confirming more then once sir

Comment: @OLDMONK; post the output please, BTW your snippet is still not working ;). try including your jQuery file **before** any other code in the snippet

Comment: @J.M.Echevarría i am getting account number once in the log

Comment: @J.M.Echevarría so this is getting weird here..it is working in firefox not in chrome

Comment: @OLDMONK; please update your question with the code you are currently using

Comment: @J.M.Echevarría Thanks sir..was naive prob with chrome..fixed it now..Thank you so much..:) Marking this as answer.